# CSS: How do I make an element scale itself so that it doesn't overflow its max-width?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create PDFs from webpages for small-screen devices. One major problem is that some elements often overflow their `max-width`, and go off-screen, and thus not get captured in the PDF. I want these elements to automatically shrink (ala `zoom: 0.5`) so as to not overflow their `max-width`. Is this possible?

PS: I am using this custom CSS to set their `max-width`:

```css
    img, .MathJax, .MathJax *, .MathJax_Display, .MathJax_Preview, .mjx-chtml, .mjx-math, .mjx-math *, .mwe-math-element, .mwe-math-element * {
        max-width: 90vw !important;
        text-align: left !important;
    }
```

Here is an example file: https://files.zii.lilf.ir/tmp/Meta-Learning%20Learning%20to%20Learn%20Fast.html

You can see an overflowing element here:
[image]

Comment: A PDF isn't a viewport, so vw probably doesn't work, what happens if you try max-width: 100% instead? How CSS behaves in a PDF is also a question of how the PDF generator script works, it is often pretty archaic with inline style tags etc.

Comment: @anatolhiman I am using puppeteer to export the PDF. I think it uses the "print" viewport. I'll try `max-width: 100%`.